# Selenium WebDriver Generic Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am exploring selenium web driver in c#. I want to make my test as generic as possible.What i want is that when my form loads all the text fields are identified and filled in with some dummy data. When I use the switch statement as specified below only first text field is filled up. How can I make it get all the fields and fill them one by one

```
foreach (var group in form.GroupFormFields)
{
   foreach (var field in group.FormFields)
   {
      var fieldId = "txt_" + field.field_title;

      switch (field.field_type_id)
      {
         case "textfield":
            var textfield = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@type='text']"));
            textfield.SendKeys("abc");
            //field.field_title
            //fill the form field
            break;
         case "email":
            var email = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@type='email']"));
            email.SendKeys("xyz@gmail.com");
            break;
         case "password":
            var password = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@type='password']"));
            password.SendKeys("Abc1234%");
            break;
         case "checkbox":
            var checkbox = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@type='checkbox']"));
            checkbox.Click();
            break;
            default:
            break;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: how many total fields you have on page?

Comment: @GaurangShah  Every form have different number of fields however i have total 8 different types of fields

Comment: then making a switch case is not a good idea, rather create a function which takes all this values and fill the form. you can utilize and override this function for each page.

Answer (score 1):

Switch case is to execute particular code on particular condition, so based on what you are passing as `caseField` as particular case will be invoked **Not All**.

If you want to fill all the input fields with dummy data, the simple thing is to get all the input elements and iterate though them. I don't C#, however JAVA and C# is very similar so perhpehs you could understand this code.

```
List<WebElement> inputs = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input"));
for(WebElement input: inputs){
    input.sendKeys("filled through automation");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Develop automation project using selenium can be hard to maintain since sometimes we required to automate big and complicated systems, best practice is to use [Page Object](http://www.assertselenium.com/automation-design-practices/page-object-pattern/) design pattern.
Implementing Page Object in an automation project will help the coder to stick to the SOLID principles.
You can wrap your page object with a class that in charge on the business logic such - fill the form.
Please review the example below

[image]

Wrap it and implement the fill details section

[image]

Now all you have to do is to call pageObjectContainer.FillDetails(submit: true)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a List with:

- Key: id of the input
- Value: value you want to input

the create a for loop looking through the List, findind the Element by Key and input with Value.